# Python desktop client hangs while iterating on excel data containing urls

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, python-requests

I am new to python and i made a web scraping script, it works fine when im using a maximum of 80 urls.

I added a progress bar and it shows me that the script gets stuck after 95 url loops. I have tried it with different website urls in the list and it still gets stuck.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Here is the script:

```
data = pd.read_excel(r'Z:\001\input.xlsx')
urllist = data['IDE_WEBSITE'].tolist()

wordlist = ('woord1', 'woord2')
results = []
errors = []

for word in wordlist:
    for url in tqdm(urllist):
        try:
            r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.lower(), 'lxml')
            words = soup.find_all(text=lambda text: text and word.lower() in text)
            count = len(words)
            time.sleep(1)
            if count > 0:
                result = {'url': url, 'count': count, 'the_word': word}
                results.append(result)
        except ConnectionError:
            error1 = {'url': url, 'error': 'connection_error'}
            errors.append(error1)
            urllist.remove(url)
            continue
        except BaseHTTPError:
            error2 = {'url': url, 'error': 'base_error'}
            errors.append(error2)
            urllist.remove(url)
            continue
        except ChunkedEncodingError:
            error3 = {'url': url, 'error': 'encoding_error'}
            errors.append(error3)
            urllist.remove(url)
            continue
        except MissingSchema:
            urllist.remove(url)
            continue

df_errors = pd.DataFrame(errors)
print(errors)
print(urllist)
df_results = pd.DataFrame(results)

df_results.to_excel(r'Z:\001_Personal\results_nmb_run3.xlsx', index=None, header=True)
df_errors.to_excel(r'Z:\001_Personal\errors_nmb_run3.xlsx', index=None, header=True)
```

Comment: what is the 95 and 96 url? do the urls exist/work? if you remove them from the list does it still get stuck at the same spot?

Comment: Hi, yes if i remove or replace them with other urls the script still gets stuck

Comment: add an `exception` clause for other exceptions, and try to make them print the exceptions like this
```except Exception as e:
     print(e)
```